# Use a Form input from cakePHP in a jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I'm very new to cakePHP I'm stuck here and I cannot find my solution after a long search.
So basically I have a button that work everywhere on cakephp :

```
echo $this->Form->create('Fightermove');
echo $this->Form->input('direction',array('options' => array('north'=>'north','east'=>'east','south'=>'south','west'=>'west'), 'default' => 'east'));
echo $this->Form->end('Move');
```

But when I use it on jQuery for adding a button dynamically it doesn't even appear :

```
$("#"+(CoordXJQ-1)+"-"+CoordYJQ).append('<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('Fightermove');
    echo $this->Form->input('direction',array('options' => array('north'=>'north','east'=>'east','south'=>'south','west'=>'west'), 'default' => 'east'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Move');
    ?>');
```

It does show something when I remove the Form->input line.

How to make this cakePHP function work on jQuery ?
Or maybe there is another way of doing this (but I'm still curious about how to solve this !) ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you really currently trying to run PHP code inside a JQuery ???

Comment: I know that is not really great doing this but this is the only way I found to select an id and put the cakephp code...

Comment: When I use the JsHelper : $this->Js->get('#element');

Comment: How to write cakePHP code inside the markup ?

Comment: No can't do that. JS is a client-side language and PHP is a server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

So as Raphaël Vigée already said, you can't run PHP code inside jQuery. But here is, what you can do:

In your view file (.ctp) just output the form in some hidden container, like

```
<div class="hiddenContainer" style="display:none">
  <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Fightermove');
    echo $this->Form->input('direction',array('options' => array('north'=>'north','east'=>'east','south'=>'south','west'=>'west'), 'default' => 'east'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Move');
  ?>
</div>
```

Then in your JavaScript file you can do

```
var $clone = $( ".hiddenContainer" ).children().clone();
$("#"+(CoordXJQ-1)+"-"+CoordYJQ).append($clone);
```

Comment: This could create some problems with id's, because of the cloning process. He would end up with 2 fields with id for example `FightermoveDirection`

Comment: Sure, but with something like, `$clone.attr("data-id",someNewId);` you can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute cakephp code after page render, but you can write php code in javascript and it will executed when page is loading.
Seems your javascript code has some issue with quotes
Try below code

```
$("#"+(CoordXJQ-1)+"-"+CoordYJQ).append("<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('Fightermove');
    echo $this->Form->input('direction',array('options' => array('north'=>'north','east'=>'east','south'=>'south','west'=>'west'), 'default' => 'east'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Move');
    ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to get a form in CakePHP Standards.
However, as everybody has mentioned you simple cannot have any server side code in JavaScript.

I suggest and this is extremely childish at best. if you do not know CakePHP standards, then make a web page in cakePHP with the form. open it in the browser, check its HTML by right clicking and view source and then copy that HTML in your jquery code.

This way you will get a Cake created form and you could go ahead and modify according to your needs.

I for one would not be doing it this way. I would use Clansi's solution